# Make hover to whole div by JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

When l want to make hover to div it's going to hover entire of div divs

l tried to make set height for overlay but its lost!

```
<div id="Overlay" onmouseover="hoverDown()" onmouseout="hoverUp()" onload="muteOther()">

#Overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}

function hoverUp() {
    var a = document.getElementById("Overlay");

    a.style.opacity = "0";
    a.style.transition = "all 1s";

}

function hoverDown() {
    var a = document.getElementById("Overlay");
    a.style.opacity = "1";

    setTimeout(function () {
        a.style.opacity = "0";
        a.style.transition = "all 1s";
    }, 4000);

}
```

When l will move the cursor to the div its Overlay appear and when its out Overlay despair

Comment: You need to add some content/element inside div and add hover up/down on that element. if you give 100% height/width to div then it will get parent height/width. It's obvious that it will take on whole div.

Comment: there is some content, but it's not full of div it occupy only some parts of it and when l move cursor to them its going to hover but l want to make whole dib onhover

Answer (score 0):

Try include the JavaScript inside a `<script>` Tag. And in addition you can use `attr_for_div=func(this)` and `func(this)` in js which `this` is equal to `var a=doc...`.